# Apache filter request hostname comparison does not work

Tags: c, apache, filter, hostname

I'm new to writing apache output filters and even more to writing them in c. I've taken a sample filter (mod_substitute) source and am trying to make it work only if the request is for a specific host. I need to make this a programatic feature and not configuration wise for my own reasons.

I am using the following code to try this:

```
request_rec *req = f->r;

ngf_module_ctx *ctx = f->ctx;


/* Test to see if this is a domain that needs optimization */
if (req->hostname != "localhost") {
    ap_pass_brigade(f->next, bb);
    return APR_SUCCESS;
}
```

using debug printing I saw that the req->hostname value does show up as localhost, however the comparison itself fails.

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a pointer equality operator (`!=`) to compare strings. This is C, remember -- you have to use a function like `strcmp` to compare strings.

If you haven't worked in C before, writing an Apache module is probably not a great place to start. Back up and get familiar with the language first.

Comment: Thanks. I managed tosolve it using the Apache apr natural comparison.